# Could this nauplius eat?

Tags: creature-design, fantasy-races, anatomy, food, sea-creatures

The nauplius of my world is a large pleustonic bivalve. It is around 3ft long. It floats belly-up on the surface, with an oddly-shaped shell that exposes the front and middle part of its ventral face above the water

However, this raises the issue of how it would eat: Its food will be found in the water, but the mouth will be in air

Is there a biologically realistic way for this nauplius to get its food into its mouth?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, without knowing much about the creature’s anatomy or why it needs to be above water- maybe it could “dip” its face below the water slightly for certain periods of time. That way, it could consume particles near the water’s surface, and poke its head back up when it needs to.

Comment: I saw one yesterday! It seemed to be looking up at large flocks of noisy seagulls flying in circle with it's tiny mouth open wide then I nicknamed it bottom feeder ;P

Comment: Does this animal have any protection against predators, like sharks and killer wales ? And I wonder how it would survive a storm. When it flips over, it will drown...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes.

As is well known, the nauplius of *I. regalia* is plesutonic and also an invert swimmer, meaning that such movement as it is capable of is accomplished whilst lying supine upon the water's surface. Any other position is made difficult by its dorsal shell that tends to keep it in place. *I. regalia* in its naupliar stage is most fascinating. As one might suppose, feeding might seem impossible for such a wee creature if its shell acts as a keel keeping its mouth out of water! But Nature in her infinite diversity of form and function has provided even for this creature's most basic of needs.

To review, a nauplius has a body from the head of which sprout its unpaired  simple eye and a small number of appendages. The eye of *I. regalia* nauplius points down into the water and is sufficient to discern the motions of the phytoplankton and microzooplankton that comrprise its diet.

All well and good that it can see its dinner! --- but how does it eat? Providence has allowed for the evolution of a very curious solution to the feeding problem *I. regalia* faces soon after hatching. Under microscopy, it was noted by Nakatini (1987) that the ventral surface of the creature forms a depression, almost a funnel. A population of nauplii was observed from hatching and it was noted that these creatures, poor swimmers, have evolved instead to be excellent scoopers!

Rather than using their limited cephalopodes for locomotion, they instead have developped one pair of appendages that sweep the water below their bodies. A slightly sticky excretion attracts their prey and traps them all along the appendage. When sufficient prey are attached, *I regalia* simply lifts these appendages out of the water and manoeuvres them towards their mouth.

The second pair of appendages seems to have a broad scoop or paddle towards the end as well as tufts of hairlike protuberances. In one graceful motion, the first appendage draws the trapped prey through the hairs, which dislodges them onto the funnel like depression around the mouth, and the tiny scoops drop their loads of water, washing the food right into the tiny creature's ever hungry mouth!

Answer (score 1):

**Your floating bivalves are photosynthetic.**

[Shedding light: a phylotranscriptomic perspective illuminates the origin of photosymbiosis in marine bivalves](https://bmcecolevol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12862-020-01614-7)

> Morphologically, the shells of some species are very similar to those
> of non-symbiotic fragines and expose symbionts to light via shell
> gaping (Fig. 1a, c). In contrast, others exhibit highly flattened
> translucent shells with sophisticated microstructures to enhance light
> acquisition, referred to as “shell windows” (Fig. 1a, d [17];)

They get their energy calories from onboard photosynthetic symbionts.  Some live in the mantle that hangs out of the shell, giant clam style.  The shell is translucent and the flesh within is green with the zooxanthella party going on inside.

At night the algal symbionts sleep.  Your buoyant clam closes up and descends thru the water table to where the good eating is, and then does its clam thing.  It does not need to eat for calories, just nitrogen and nutrients.  Daybreak and the green clams ascend to the surface.

---

Not digging the up and down?  "Plureley pleustonic!", you plead?  OK.  Birds can help.

[image: seagull on buoy]
[source](https://www.news18.com/news/buzz/sailor-who-fell-overboard-stayed-afloat-by-clinging-to-abandoned-fishing-buoy-for-14-hours-3476135.html)

Your clams often have passengers.  Seabirds like to stand on the big green shells floating around.  And where birds stand, they poop.  A dose of nitrogen rich bird poo every week or so is all the nitrogen that these photosynthetic clams need to keep their onboard farms green.